# UITableView headerView not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using `UITableView`demo, I implemented `heightForHeaderInSection` and  `viewForHeaderInSection`, but HeaderView is not visible.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have write?

Comment: Yes, need to see code.

Comment: @SyedeHussaini   Thank you very much，yesterday I find the bug 。Because I forget to  write  'self.tableView.delegate=self'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `heightForHeaderInSection` is implemented and a valid non-zero value is returned.
This [link](http://ansi-tech.com/ios-swiftobj-c-uitableview-section-not-showing/) will help you resolve this issue.